# there are two textboxes, want to identify on which textbox the cursor is or is focused

Tags: asp.net

I have two textboxes, i want the system to identify on which textbox the cursor is. If the cursor is at second textbox then the value writen in second textbox is submitted. There is a possibility that both text box contain value but only the one having cursor on must be seleted

Comment: Use Javascript and set a variable on focus.

Comment: It's nice that you want that. Have you tried anything to do so? Also, it sounds like you'd better just solve this serverside: post both textboxes and check which one has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript is one of the possible options. May be this can help you give a very very basic idea on where to start with...

```
var txtFocus = null;

  window.onload = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      var fcsdTxt= inputs[i];

      if(fcsdTxt.type == 'text') {
        fcsdTxt.onfocus = function() {
          txtFocus = this; // set the variable 'txtFocus' declared at top
        }
        fcsdTxt.onblur = function() {
          txtFocus = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now  check the variable "txtFocus" when you want to see which textbox has focus,

```
if(txtFocus)
    alert(txtFocus.id + ': ' + txtFocus.value);
  else
    alert('No textbox focused');
```

Now, you have to make sure you get the value of txtFocus on server side. So use a hidden field on your page and set the value in Javascript:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="fcsTxt" runat="server" Visible="true" />
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('<%= fcsTxt.ClientID %>').value = txtFocus;
```

and definitely, accessing the value of Hidden field in Asp.Net code behind file is :

```
string ID = fcsTxt.Value;
```